# XPath for all nodes with children that do not match certain criteria?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to find certain elements in a webpage, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried with the `not` function, but it doesn't work due to the scenario.

```
<table id="uniqueId">
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="row" onclick="do_a_thing">
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" onclick="do_a_thing">
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row" onclick="do_a_thing">
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to select all the `tr` that don't have an `input` with `value=2` as a child.

I tried: `//tr[.//input[not(@value='2')]]`, but it doesn't work because the `tr`s also have another `input` with value `1`.

Answer (score 2):

This XPath,

```
//tr[not(td/input/@value='2')]
```

selects all `tr`s without `td/input`s with a `value` attribute value equal to `2`, as requested.

Comment: Thank you @kjhughes that worked. Now I have another question related to your answer. I thought that if you want to specify a child of the node you need to use either `./` or `.//` but I tried the same way you wrote it and it works. Why is it looking for descendant inside the `[]` instead of looking for attributes in the current node?

Comment: (1) You could rewrite `td` less concisely as `./td`; both select `td` children of the context element.  OTOH, `.//input` would select `input` descendents at any depth.   (2) The predicate (`[]`) is applied to the element you wish to select, `tr`.